# Is there a deep reason why $\mathbb{C}$ is a topological field w.r.t. the Euclidean norm?

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, galois-theory, normed-spaces, topological-groups

Today I realised that I didn’t remember how to prove that the complex numbers are a topological field w.r.t. to the metric induced by the Euclidean norm $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I think the usual proof is boring and yet elementary, but still I have always thought that the fact that the field structure on $\mathbb{C}$ is compatible with the Euclidean norm is some kind of miracle.

I would be tempted to ask here if people share the same feeling as me that the continuity of the field structure on $\mathbb{C}$ w.r.t. the Euclidean norm is something very deep even if its proof is quite basic and unremarkable, or if I am just deluding myself.

But I realise this question is not appropriate for this site.

I will try to make it more acceptable by asking

> Is there some conceptual reason, lurking behind the usual proof, that makes things work?
> Is this related to the structure of the Galois group of $\mathbb{C}$ over  $\mathbb{R}$, or maybe by the fact that the Euclidean norm happens to be the square root of the algebraic norm on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about continuity of multiplication and inversion? It seems like the answer for addition and negation comes from $\mathbb{C}$ being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the fact that complex multiplication is deeply tied to rotations, and the Euclidean norm is the unique one (up to some constant factor) which is invariant under rotations.

Comment: You can obtain the complex numbers by [Cayley-Dickson doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) the reals. I've never thought about how topology should tie in with the construction.

Comment: @Jackson I am obviously talking about the multiplication and inversion, as addition is the same

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos A note: the complex numbers are a topological field with respect to any norm, since all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent. Only a tiny portion of those has anything to do with rotations.

Comment: @lisyarus: yes, I noticed that, too, after writing a long answer detailing why complex multiplication makes the Euclidean norm multiplicative. But sadly that's not what was asked for.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I briefly read your answer and found it interesting. The determinant of the matrix $A$ you wrote can be seen as a way to compute the algebraic norm, so your point view was related to the algebraic one.

Comment: @Tyrone I did not know about that! This could be something along the lines of what I was looking for. Infact the norm given by the CD doubling construction to the quaternions is the same as the one on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and similarly for the octonions and $\mathbb{R}^8.$ At this point maybe I should look into Hurwitz's theorem.

Comment: Why do you think "the fact that the field structure on $\mathbb{C}$ is compatible with the Euclidean norm is some kind of miracle"? No matter how I think about the multiplication and the inversion, like geometrically or from the "boring" definition (like $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (ac-bd,ad+bc)$ or something), it seems clear enough that they should be continuous wrt. to the standard topology, and as stated above, any "norm" induces that topology.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen As I said, I am aware that maybe I am just deluding myself and the fact is prob no big ideal.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Still, I think that taking the top. ring $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and defining a new multiplication that is completely unrelated to topology and comes from polynomial multiplication modulo $X^2+1,$ and then obtaining a top. field which is homeomorphic to the previous one, thus being able to add such a rich algebraic structure whilst keeping the same space, is something that amazes me. From a different pov, the fact that the topological norm is the square root of the algebraic norm strikes me as something quite deep about complex numbers.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen And the fact that all norms are equivalent does not mean much about my question.